# Convert or use north, east, south and west coords to north-east and south-west for checking in-bounds

Tags: mysql, coordinates, bounds

I have two tables, one table which contains countries with their north, east, south and west coords of a rectangle of each country, this is the structure,

```
+--------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| boundary_id  | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| country      | varchar(100)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| country_code | varchar(4)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| geo_west     | float(10,6)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| geo_north    | float(10,6)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| geo_south    | float(10,6)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| geo_east     | float(10,6)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now, for the other table is stored locations of users, I need their location (latitude and longitude) to match against the table to check whether they fall in the desired country chosen. In other words, only pick up the users that fall within the bounds of the chosen country.

This is the data from the table (selected 4),

```
+-------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+------------+------------+-------------+
```

| boundary_id | country        | country_code | geo_west    | geo_north  | geo_south  | geo_east    |
+-------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+------------+------------+-------------+
|         218 | Afghanistan    | AF           |   60.478436 |  38.483425 |  29.377470 |   74.879463 |
|         224 | Albania        | AL           |   19.293968 |  42.665615 |  39.648354 |   21.068476 |
|         188 | Algeria        | DZ           |   -8.673869 |  37.093727 |  18.960026 |   11.979549 |
|         229 | American Samoa | AS           | -170.841339 | -14.162115 | -14.382480 | -169.416061 |
+-------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+------------+------------+-------------+

The user table,

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+
| user_id | latitude  | longitude |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
|       6 | 51.495010 | -0.071583 |
|       7 | 51.204731 |  1.251486 |
|       8 | 51.261860 |  1.327887 |
|       9 | 51.487850 | -0.071926 |
|      10 | 51.498699 | -0.201187 |
|      11 | 51.436462 | -0.100937 |
|      12 | 51.331093 |  0.829124 |
|      13 | 51.565121 | -0.065918 |
|      14 | 51.493568 | -0.248566 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

Would I need to convert the coords to north-east and south-west or not and how to effectively match against those?

I prefer to avoid geolocation services due to their limits.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be using some sort of geolocation service for this (i.e. Google Maps).  Just knowing the northernmost, southernmost, etc. coordinates of a country does not imply that shape of the country at all.

For example the northernmost coordinates of the US (in Alaska), the southern and westermost coordinates (Hawaii), and the eastermost (Maine) would draw a huge rectangle which could also include large swaths of Canada, Mexico, the Caribbean, etc.

How would you deal with all the overlaps if treating countries like rectangles?

Comment: I prefer to avoid geolocation services, many of them have limits.

Answer (score 0):

@Mike Brant has just described the main point I was going to raise.

MySQL supports spatial data types so I suggest you take the following approach:

1. Find a source of country bounding polygons online (Googling would probably get you most of the way there)
2. Load these polygons into MySQL and store them as spatial features (geometry objects, not just basic coordinate strings)
3. Store your user locations as spatial features
4. Use MySQL's [spatial relation functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html) to determine whether a user (point) is within a country (polygon)

If this is the path you want to take you should consider moving over to http://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: I got the coordinates from here, http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/info/all.html

Comment: @BurningtheCodeigniter the numbers may be correct but you've got them in the wrong order. -14.38 would be the south boundary

Comment: @BurningtheCodeigniter also please tell me you didn't type all those numbers in manually! Changing the .html extension to .json gives a parseable response, which - if you search for American Samoa, shows the ordinates and which boundary they refer to. http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/info/all.json

Comment: LOL lucky I didn't, I parsed the JSON than parsing the HTML, I updated the table with the values, now what could I do?

Comment: @BurningtheCodeigniter honestly I think your only viable option is to take a different approach. Re-read Mike Brant's point regarding rectangles and overlap. I've updated my answer with a simpler suggestion

Comment: Do you have any country bounding polygons that you'd recommend?

Comment: @BurningtheCodeigniter I googled 'country boundary polygons'. This is the first result: http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php view the data in QGIS and then learn how to load it into MySQL

Comment: Sorry to bring this up again, but it is a bit of a hassle to try read them in QCIS since I don't know how, but isn't there already one as a SQL data dump?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea... Get a 360x360 bitmap that holds a world map. Paint every country with a different color in RGB, like, #010000 for id 1 country, #020000 for id 2 country etc (yes except water, entire world would end up in shades of red). Then when you want to check a user, take the x-y pixel (remember, it will go from -180 to +180, so it actually will be x+180, y+180), find the color of that pixel and from that the country ?

Preparing that bitmap might be a lot of work, but once that is done, rest should be quite easy.

As I said, just an idea.

Comment: for better resolution, scale the map upwards and scale the long/lat values accordingly, should be trivial.

Comment: this is an interesting approach but it has a reinventing-the-wheel kind of feeling to it... There are very impressive Open Source products available that can do this and a whole lot more

Comment: BurningtheCodeigniter well, your question was about long/lat so I kind of assumed you were. Countries etc.
@tomfumb you probably are quite right. As I said, just an idea.